# python pypi: ConfigParser blowing up when pointing to certain repo

Tags: python, pypi

I have a package (poorly named) `python-reusable` that I am trying to upload to a PyPi repository. I can upload it to another repository fine, but when trying to upload to this particular repo, I get a stack trace:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_reusable.egg-info/requires.txt
writing python_reusable.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to python_reusable.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_reusable.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'python_reusable.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'python_reusable.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt

running check
creating python_reusable-0.2.0

[redacted]
....

Writing python_reusable-0.2.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'python_reusable-0.2.0' (and everything under it)
running register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    install_requires=reqs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/register.py", line 10, in run
    orig.register.run(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/register.py", line 46, in run
    self._set_config()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/register.py", line 72, in _set_config
    config = self._read_pypirc()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/config.py", line 76, in _read_pypirc
    current['username'] = config.get(server, 'username')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'global'
```

When I try to upload it to another pypi server, it works:

```
Writing python_reusable-0.2.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'python_reusable-0.2.0' (and everything under it)
running register
Registering python_reusable to [REDACTED]
Server response (200): OK
running upload
Submitting dist/python_reusable-0.2.0.tar.gz to [REDACTED]
Server response (200): OK
```

If there was something wrong with the server, or the .pypirc, I feel that error should propogate up so I know what is going on. So, what is going on?

I do not use ConfigParser anywhere in this package myself.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in distutils. Will file an issue there.

I had in my .pypirc

```
[distutils]
index-servers = 
    exists
    not_in_this_file

[exists]
    ...

#nothing else
```

I think there is an uncaught exception in distuitls that does not detect the mising `not_in_this_file` section.